# How can we effectively use Git in a server-orientated workflow?

Tags: git, workflow

Integrating git into a company that has never used it before is a tough thing. I think its super important and I'd like to introduce the team to git, but I cannot change whole workflows in my company. Additionally, I didn't have a lot of contact with Git myself.

The following workflow is probably problematic:

We have a Server with two folders, one for the live site (optional if we create a completely new website) and one for development purposes. Locally, we mount the development server as a Volume, so we can compile and upload SASS files on save (using the Atom editor). Every change is on the development server and we can directly see the results. Since we are working for a lot of different customers with different hosting providers it is essential to see how the environment affects our programming. This workflow is all but failsafe, but it allows us to start working on other projects (from colleagues) without setting up anything.

Alot of agencies around us work exactly like that, but I'm sure it's not the professional way to do it.

**My question: Can we integrate Git without changing the workflow too much?**

Comment: Just to be clear, this isn't about git specifically, but about moving from a situation with no source control at all into one that *does* have source control? And presumably from "all developers are working on a single server, all at the same time" to something more isolated? I would definitely advise the company to take a step back and at least consider revising the whole workflow (e.g. to where one developer trying something without committing to it doesn't break everyone else...)

Comment: Out of curiosity : how many developers work on those projects ?

Comment: We work with seven developers on our projects, mostly in one office, from time to time with homeoffice.

Changing the workflow in its core sure isn't impossible, but it will consume lots of hours and I'm not in the position to decide anything, but I sure can recommend changes to our workflow.

Comment: :mindblown: Ok. About code editing : do you edit files on your own computer, and copy them on each save ? or does everyone edit the files straight from Server/development ?

Comment: A bit of both I guess. Opening a file on the mounted server volume loads it into memory, and on save its copied back to the server.

A few months ago, we had a local folder with the files we were working on. Using SASS, we need to push not only the file we are editing, but generated (.css) files as well. The lack of a watcher feature in Transmit forces us to mount a server as a volume, changes on any files are directly uploaded automatically.

Answer (score 0):

*Technically*, you describe how you *deploy* your code on Server.

You can *version* everyone's code and still keep the same ... erm ... workflow.